# Trying for pagination using reactQuery

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, react-query

**react-query**
I am fetching dummy data from json placeholder and i want to paginate; ie. only one post at the current page. if i am not passing '${page}' in the url then it is resulting all the data but when i am passing it is giving an error.
**"Users.jsx:6 GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/undefined 404".**
the first parameter of useQuery is an array having a constant value 1, it indicates the desired user with id 1 and so on..

```
    import React,{useState} from 'react';
    import {useQuery} from 'react-query';
    import User from './User';

    const fetchUsers=async(key,page)=>{
        const res=await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${page}`); 
        return res.json();
    }

    const Users = () => {
        const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
        const {data,status}=useQuery(["users", 1], fetchUsers);
        console.log(data);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="Listtype">Users List</h1>
                {status==='loading'&& <i className="fas fa-spinner fa-4x fa-spin"></i>}
                {status==='error' && (
                    <h2 className="text-center text-danger">There is some error</h2>
                ) }
                {status==='success' && (
                    <div>
                       <h1>{JSON.stringify(data)}</h1>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default Users
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `react-query` `v3` you can change your code to

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import User from './User'

const fetchUsers = async (page) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${page}`)
  return res.json()
}

const Users = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const { data, status } = useQuery(['users', page], () => fetchUsers(page))
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="Listtype">Users List</h1>
      {status === 'loading' && <i className="fas fa-spinner fa-4x fa-spin"></i>}
      {status === 'error' && (
        <h2 className="text-center text-danger">There is some error</h2>
      )}
      {status === 'success' && (
        <div>
          <h1>{JSON.stringify(data)}</h1>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Users
```

Hopefully, it can help you!

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but please amend it explaining why that fixes it. With v3, the query key is no longer spread as arguments onto the query function, but a `queryContext` is injected containing the `queryKey`. Your solution "bypasses" this with an inline function, but `const fetchUsers = async ({ queryKey }) => ...` would also work :)